# App has been approved on appstore and move to Ready to sale. App Availability in countries is pending

Tags: flutter, mobile, deployment, app-store, hybrid-mobile-app

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its almost from a week in Ready to sale but App Availability in countries is Processing to Available so what will be the solution the is no chat support to appstore? how can we address the issue. This is a private app. Private — Available as a custom app on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager. So how can we access it....

Comment: Have you find a solution to this issue?